# When adding a package to "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" from Github, how can I specify the version?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I am building an iOS app in XCode 12.3. For that, I am adding a library using `General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content -> Add Package Dependency`. Pasting the link to the Github library (in this case it's https://github.com/WeTransfer/Mocker) adds the current version of the library (2.4.0), but I want to add a previous version to avoid a bug in the latest version. Linking to a release (e.g. https://github.com/WeTransfer/Mocker/releases/tag/2.2.0) does not work.

How can I add this package with the version of 2.2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same repo url:

[image]

At the next screen, just change the version rule for that Swift package to **Exact** and fill in the version that you want to use:

[image]